# How to build dependent measures in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have 2 table visuals using data and some filters, I need to create an index column to number rows from 1. I used 2 tables on different pages so as to display full data, but the table visual format and rules are exactly the same.

I used the following measure:

```
Index = 
RANKX (
    ALLSELECTED ( 'dataframe' ),
    'dataframe'[Time Since Recorded],
    MAX ( 'dataframe'[Time Since Recorded])
)
```

which seemed to work on the single visual/single page. However, it starts from 1 again if used in another visual (as expected). For example, visual 1 has 15 rows with index number 1 - 15, on the second page, for visual 2, I want to have index starting from 16 onwards. However, as I used the same measure, it will start from 1. How can I create dependent measures so that visual 2 will be dependent on visual 1, and start index from 16?

I tried to add the maximum value of the first measure(in the first page) to the second measure but it always gives the maximum value of the second measure(in the second page). I presume the maximum function applies only to the current measure.

Or is there a way for me to extract the maximum value of the first measure as a constant so that I could use it in the second measure?

Comment: DAX measures are always calculated from the underlying data model, not from visuals. I'd recommend to re-write the question: show your data model, provide data sample, and describe the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Populate a calculated column of Index in Table1 using

```
Column = RANKX(ALLSELECTED('dataframe'), 'dataframe'[Time Since Recorded],,ASC)
```

Populate a calculated column of Index in Table2 using

```
Index = RANKX(ALLSELECTED('dataframe'), 'dataframe'[Time Since Recorded],,ASC) + MAX('dataframe'[Column])
```

Comment: This does not solve their problem. They want measures, not calculated columns.

Comment: Using ALLSELECTED in a calculated column does not make any sense.